# Do instance methods strongly reference their objects?

Tags: java, reference

Does `myObject::someMethod` strongly reference `myObject`?  For some background, consider these two classes:

```java
class TakesRunnable {
    private Runnable runner;

    TakesRunnable(Runnable runner) {
        this.runner = runner;
    }

    public void run() {
        runner.run();
    }
}

class Foo {
    public void runMe() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I were to instantiate a `Foo` object, create `new TakesRunnable(foo::runMe)`, and then lose my local reference to `foo`, would `foo` be garbage-collected underneath me or would my `TakesRunnable` object maintain a strong reference to it?  I would imagine the latter but that's because I spend a lot of time in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [instance-method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) maintain a reference to the object they relate to.

So in your case, the object `foo` will remain uncollectable until that method reference goes out of scope.